# Javascript Regular Expressions Capture

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to capture this: `<!.This is a string.!>`
It can contain anything within the `<!. .!>`

So I tried this: `<\!\..+\.\!>/g`

Which didn't work. I've been trying to fix this for days now with no success. I want to capture the whole string including the `<!. .!>`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: forget the `/g` and it will work

Comment: @jordan still alive ?!

Comment: Jordan @tuga I am sure Tuga and I are both wondering what the third answer (which you picked) provided that the two earlier answers didn't already provide.

Comment: He got me the delimiters and what's inside of them.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, Jordan. Initially you hadn't said `I want to capture the whole string including the <!. .!>` so to Tuga and me it sounded like you wanted the string, not the delimiters. Wishing you a good weekend.

Comment: If you could remove the downvote. I was overstating myself quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
Since the OP edited his post to specify that he doesn't just want to capture the string but also the delimiters, I have moved out the capturing parentheses from `<!\.(.*?)\.!>` to `(<!\..*?\.!>)`

This should do it:

```
var myregexp = /(<!\..*?\.!>)/m;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
} else {
    result = "";
}
```

Since JS does not support lookbehinds, the idea is to match the whole string, including the delimiters, but to only capture "My String" into Group 1. Then we inspect Group 1.

Answer (score -1):

For someone that's "pretty good at Regex", this one is a no brainier.

```
var subject = "<!.This is a string.!>";
subject = subject.match(/<!\.(.*?)\.!>/);
console.log(subject[1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tuga/YzLnN/1/

Comment: Hey, like minds think alike, I just posted `Why the downvotes on Tuga and me?`

Comment: I don't know who downvoted. I didn't downvote anyone.

Comment: @Jordan I believe you!

Comment: @zx81 and it seems he likes to down-vote others... let it be :)